# Communication through events between an entity and its repository in Doctrine2

Tags: events, entity, doctrine-orm

I'm starting to use Doctrine 2 in a project with a "Group" entity that can inherit from another Group, having the following schema: `id | parent_id | name`

Because the hierarchy can go deep, I use a linking table, "group_group", using this schema: `ancestor_id | descendant_id | depth`

The idea is that any group is linked to all of its ancestors and descendants, and the `depth` field indicates the distance of the relationship, so that I don't have to iterates through parents or children using many SQL requests, a single one can get all the results.
I tried to use Doctrine's `ManyToMany` relation but I could not get it to be ordered by the `depth` field, so instead I use the entity's repository to get the related ancestors and descendants.

Because an entity can not access its repository, I would like to know if there is a way for an entity to dispatch events that can be listened by its repository, so that when an entity tries to access its ancestors/descendants, the repository can respond?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

An `Entity` shouldn't have a concrete reference to a `Repository` but there isn't anything wrong with defining an `Interface` and have your `Repository` implement this interface and injecting it into the `Entity`.

Similar to this solution [Doctine 2 Restricting Associations with DQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240335/doctine-2-restricting-associations-with-dql)

```
interface TreeInterface
{
   public function findParent();
   public function findChildren();
}
```

Then your Entities.

```
class Group
{
    $repository;

    setRepository(TreeInterface $repository)
    {
        $this->tree = $repository;
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->repository->findParent($this);
    }

    public function getChildren()
    {
         return $this->repository->findChildren($this);
    }
}

class GroupRepository extends EntityRepository implements TreeInterface
{
    public function findParent(Group $group)
    {
        return //stuff
    }

    public function findChildren(Group $group)
    {
        return //stuff
    }
}
```

And you use it this way.

```
$group = $em->find('Group', 1);
$group->setRepository($em->getRepository('Group'));
$children = $group->getChildren();
```

To avoid setting the repository each time you get a child, I would take a look at the EventManager and postLoad event and see if you can inject a TreeInterface into the Entity on load.