# Doctrine 2 Restricting Associations with DQL

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, repository-pattern, dql

There seems to be an over sight in Doctrine 2.1 where it isn't easy to return a subset 
collection for an association.

http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html#restricing-associations

The docs recommend to write a repository find method, which makes sense because that was the first thing I though of doing.

However without having a reference to the EntityManager within an Entity I can't see how you would retrieve the association's Repository and this seems to defeat the point of separating the Domain from the Database?

Is there a recommended strategy for this problem?

Here is my interpretation of their suggested solution.

```
class Category
{
    protected $id;
    protected $articles; // PesistentCollection
    protected $em; // The EntityManager from somewhere?

    public function getVisableArticles()
    {
        return $this->em->getRepository('Article')
                    ->getVisibleByCategory($this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Having entitymanager in an entity isn't a good thing in any case
   (inject your repository instead)
2. Category isn't the only root for articles because it can't daterimne what articles you need, so you need a repository for articles.

What i would do:

```
class Category
{
    protected $id;
    protected $articles; // PesistentCollection

    public function getVisableArticles(IArticleRepository $articleRepository)
    {
        return $articleRepository->getVisibleByCategory($this);
    }
}

interface IArticleRepository
{
    function getVisibleByCategory(Category $category);
}
```

Your doctrine's repository would implement IArticleRepository and the class won't know anything about your data storage/doctrine.

Comment: Yes using an interface is the answer, should of thought of that! I'm guessing there isn't any kind of dependency injection during entity mapping, If I had a setter for an IArticleRepository?

Comment: There's no dependency injection built-in, doctrine handles only management objects in a database

Comment: Another thought, are the results cached in anyway? if I were to create a new visible Article add it to the PesistentCollection and then call getVisibleArticles() again would my new Article appear in the returned array?

Comment: Depends on how you implement your repository. By default it's not cached