# Doctrine 2 Restricting Associations Dynamically

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm

So I have the following.

```
/** @Entity */
class Job {

    /** @OneToMany(targetEntity="Invoice" ...) */  INVERSE SIDE
    protected $invoices;

    public function getInvoices() {
        return $this->invoices;
    }
}
```

Ideally I would like to filter the invoices returned against an ACL.  So these are my thoughts so far.

1.) I could write Repository methods, and use translate my ACL logic into DQL.

```
// in some client code....

// $constraint would contain the DQL logic needed to restrict association returned   
$constraint = new InvoiceAccessConstraintFactory($user);


$jobs = $jobRepository->findAllSatisfying(array('status' => 'SomeStatus'), $constraint);
```

My issue with this method is that I feel like it would for one be difficult to maintain, but it would *I think* be pretty good performance wise.

2.) Use a PostLoad event listener to create a custom proxy to PersistedCollection which contains the original PersistedCollection of invoices and a custom Iterator extending FilterIterator.

```
PostLoad Listener 
public function applyACL($args){
    $job = $args->getEntity(); 

    $proxy = new InvoiceAccessProxy($job->getInvoices(), array('iteratorClass' => 'InvoiceAccessFilter', 'user' => $user)); 


    $job->setInvoices($proxy);
}

... so that in client code
foreach($job->getInvoices() as $invoice) {
    // filtered through accept method in InvoiceAccessFilter
}
```

Not sure about this though because of the proxy to PersistedCollection which I am not sure is possible. But I do like the idea of accessing $job->getInvoices() and have it return a different result set based on context.

3.) Ive read in to Doctrine2 documentation somewhere that implementing custom AST Walkers could be used to implement access control, but I have been unable to find an example. And I think this would be challenging.

4.) ..... Looking for other ideas

I guess this post comes down for my need to be able to display the same data differently based on numerous contexts.

So I am just looking for any advice anyone can give... examples, reading materials, thoughts .....

Comment: I think this is the logical solution

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240335/doctine-2-restricting-associations-with-dql